# Where can I find the name or GUID of an GPO

Tags: powershell, guid, gpo

first of all I’m quite new to GPOs and PowerShell

What i am trying to do is write a script to automatically set up the group policy I want.

After some looking around the best way I found was to use `Set-GPRegistryValue`. But to use that I would either need a GUID or a name of a policy but I can’t seem to find those.

My Question is where and how can I find the GUID and or name or a policy
(or if I should do something entirely different)

Edit: i do not have the "Goup management console" and I cannot find it in windows features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to add in a brand new Group Policy, using `New-GPO` will let you create that (and get the GUID of the created GPO), if you want to get a list of all existing GP Objects, `Get-GPO -All` will provide it for you.

Comment: The only thing is that i am working on a normal windows 10 computer and not on a server. to use `Get-GPO -All` you need the servermanger module.

Comment: @TheRWS96 `New-GPO` and `Get-GPO` along with the rest of the Group Policy cmdlets and Group Policy Management Console snapin for mmc are part of the [Remote Server Administration Toolkit (RSAT)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) which is able to be installed on Win10. This is the best way to accomplish the task you are attempting.

Comment: @BenH Hmm that could work but just a question, does this mean that to use the Group Policy cmdlets that I also have to install the RSA Toolkit on any machine where I want to run my script? or alternatively if that is the case can I just single out the Group Policy module and put it on an USB stick (or something else) and use/import it form there? What I mean is do I need the total RSA Toolkit or can I get away with just using the Group Policy module?

Comment: @TheRWS96 Group Policy is not the same as Local Policy. You don't run Group Policy cmdlets on standard hosts. They are for making policies on for your domain, and pulled down by your hosts. I don't know the answer if you could pull out the Group Policy module, probably not without a lot of work. But that's not how it's used anyways.

Comment: Get-GPO -All is listing all the GPOs and it's difficult to find the name of the exact GPO I am looking for. Is there any other way? I see that the display name and name in get-gpo output are different, so I can't grep in the command line output too.